# Jersey Http Server: Add parameters to every http method

Tags: java, http, exception, transactions, jersey

I have a Jersey Http Server and want to optimize my code. One problem I have is that I have nearly the same manual transaction handling in every method. That is what a typical method looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
public Response create(String taskJson) {

    Connection connection = null;
    try (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection()) {
        connection = mySqlConnection.getDbConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        // Add some data to the database with SQL-Statements...

        connection.commit();
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        connection.rollback();
        Logger.getInstance().logError(LOG_TAG, "Unexpected Error", e);
        return error;
    }

}
```

So the database transaction handling is very annoying and its duplicated code in every method. I want to have my methods look like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
public Response create(String taskJson, @AddedPerJerseyMagicToMyMethod Connection connection) {

        // Add some data to the database with SQL-Statements...

        return result;

}
```

So I want that a filter adds a Connection parameter to every method and that the filter automatically handles the transaction stuff(like commit, rollback on exception, etc.)

I already now how to add filters to my Jersey Http Server and also know who to handle uncaught exceptions. But I have no idea how I can add custom parameters to every method and access this parameters in the Exception Handler.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to solve this by adding parameters to the JAX-RS Resources, because that's got nothing to do with it.

In the JAX-RS Resource methods, you should only read and validate the request parameters, and then hand the task that is requested to a different class doing the database operations.

Additionally you should possibly work with a pool of database connections instead of creating a new one for each call, if this is more than an exercise. (But don't implement the pooling yourself.)

To add a little practical hint: You can let your resource classes extend a base class with a *context-annotated* method, which will then **be called before the acutal requested resource method**:

```
public class BaseResource {

   protected Object someVar;

  @Context
  public void setServletContext( ServletContext servletContext ) {
      someVar = ...;
  }
}
```

By this, each of your resource methods will have `someVar` set.

As said, I would not use this for a thing so complicated as the database transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "In the JAX-RS Resource methods, you should only read and validate the request parameters, and then hand the task that is requested to a different class doing the database operations." Do you have an example for that or an source where I can read something about that?

Comment: And is there also an annotation (like @Context) for a method to be called after the resource method?

Comment: There is something, added to JAX-RS in version 2: "Filters and Interceptor" were added to the spec. I don't personally know these, as I am still sticking with JAX-RS 1 (!) :-)  but it sounds like worth a look. O'Reilly book excerpt: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9781449361433/ch12.html